# Question on maps of modules (tensor hom)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $M,N$ be locally free $A$-modules over a commutative ring $A$.
Let $f: M \rightarrow M\otimes N$ be a map. Then this can be seen as an element of $f \in M^*\otimes M \otimes N=(M\otimes M^*)^*\otimes N\cong (M^*\otimes M)^*\otimes N$, that is a map $End(M)\rightarrow N$. I'm wondering, under this correspondence, how can I describe this map $End(M) \rightarrow N$ induced by $f$? It seems to me it must be $g \mapsto tr(f\circ g)\in N$,  but I'm not entirely sure. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

We write $M^\ast=\mathrm{Hom}(M,A)$ for a finitely generated projective $A$-module $M$.

The isomorphism $M^\ast\otimes M\otimes N\to\mathrm{Hom}(M,M\otimes N)$ sends $\theta\otimes m\otimes n$ to the homomorphism $x\mapsto \theta(x)m\otimes n$.

Similarly, the isomorphism $M\otimes N\to\mathrm{Hom}(M^\ast,N)$ sends $m\otimes n$ to the morphism $\phi\mapsto\phi(m)n$. Combined with the tensor-hom adjunction we get
$$M^\ast\otimes M\otimes N \cong \mathrm{Hom}(M,\mathrm{Hom}(M^\ast,N)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(M\otimes M^\ast,N) $$
sending $\theta\otimes m\otimes n$ to the map $x\otimes\phi\mapsto\theta(x)\phi(m)n$.

We now want to identify $M\otimes M^\ast\cong\mathrm{End}(M)$, sending $x\otimes\phi$ to $y\mapsto\phi(y)x$. From the previous paragraph we had the map $x\otimes\phi\mapsto\theta(x)\phi(m)$, which now becomes the map $\mathrm{End}(M)\to A$, $f\mapsto \theta(f(m))$.

Putting this together we get the map
$$ M^\ast\otimes M\otimes N \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{End}(M),N) $$
sending $\theta\otimes m\otimes n$ to the map $g\mapsto \theta(g(m))n$.

Finally, assume that $N$ is finite free, with basis $n_i$. Then given $f:M\to M\otimes N$, we can write this as $\sum_if_in_i$ with $f_i\in\mathrm{End}(M)$, so that $f(m)=\sum_if_i(m)n_i$. We next write $f_i=\sum_j\theta_{ij}\otimes m_{ij}$, so that $f_i(x)=\sum_j\theta_{ij}(x)m_{ij}$ for all $x\in M$. Then $f$ is sent to the map $\mathrm{End}(M)\to N$, $g\mapsto\sum_{ij}\theta_{ij}(g(m_{ij}))n_i=\sum_i\mathrm{tr}(f_ig)n_i$.

So there is an expression involving traces (of endomorphisms of $M$), but I don’t know what you mean when you write the trace of a map $M\to M\otimes N$.